# IntelliSense for Angular Material CSS Class doesn't appear when executed

Tags: css, angular, visual-studio-code, angular-material, intellisense

After I run the command "ng add @angular/material" when I write HTML code in VSCode, no IntelliSense appears for Material CSS classes.
For example, for the code line `<div class="mat-display-3">This is the page header<\div>` when I type "mat" inside the CSS class name, it does not show a CSS list for me to select.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. The extension [IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML](https://IntelliSense%20for%20CSS%20class%20names%20in%20HTML) works for me, even though there is a small glitch in this extension. You have to type the whole tag , move to another line and come back to class name.

Answer (score 0):

Add Angular Language support and snippets.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template

Make sure TS is started.

```
tsc --init
```

And add Angular Language Service, Angular Material v10 snippets.

```
Hit Cmd-Shift-P (macOS) or Ctrl-Shift-P (Windows, Linux)
Select Install Extension
Choose the extension Angular Material v10 snippets
Reload Visual Studio Code
```

Comment: Angular Language Service 14 has already been installed. It works for tag event and attributes such as style, but not class.